# Kinetic average energy of $N$ particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Really quick doubt: we know that $\overline{E_c}=\frac32 kT$ where $k=1.38\cdot 10^{-23}\frac{J}{K\cdot particles}$ but particles isn't really a unit, I know, but imagine they ask me about $N$ particles. Would it just be then $E_c=\frac32 kT\cdot N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the risk of sounding unpurposefully passive-aggresive, the answer is simply:

Yes.

Comment: Which is a reason why "check my work" questions are usually off topic.